# Server socket is not blocking in C

Tags: c, sockets

In my application, I have a daemon that has accepts new connections using the following piece of code.

```
int serverSocket = socket(AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (serverSocket < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error (%d) while creating socket.",serverSocket);
    return -1;
}
struct sockaddr_un server;

memset(&server, 0, sizeof server);
server.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
// the first byte of sun_path should be '\0' for abstract namespace
strcpy(server.sun_path + 1, sockname);

// note that sockaddr_len should be set to the exact size of the buffer that is used.
socklen_t sockaddr_len = sizeof(server.sun_family) + strlen(sockname) + 1;
if (bind(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sockaddr_len) < 0) {
    close(serverSocket);
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to bind the server socket");
    return -1;
}

if (listen(serverSocket, 1) < 0) {
    close(serverSocket);
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to listen on server socket");
    return -1;
}
int clientSocket = accept(serverSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&server, &sockaddr_len);
if (clientSocket < 0) {
    close(serverSocket);
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to accept client connection");
    return -1;
}
```

My client connects successfully and after "accept" I start reading from the clientSocket. When I read from the clientSocket, I want to block. Instead it looks like the read is non-blocking. How can the server perform a blocking read?

The "read" below returns immediately without an error even though there is no data sent from the client.

```
mSocket = clientSocket;
if (mSocket <= 0) {
    return -1;
}

int n = read(mSocket, (uint8_t*)data, len);
if (n < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data from stream: %d", errno);
    return -1;
}
fprintf(stderr, "Reading %d bytes of %d data from stream\n", n, len);
```

I have tried setting the timeout on clientSocket using the setSockOpt command but that doesnt work. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have not set the socket to non-blocking, it will block. So there's a error somewhere else. What did the `"Reading %d bytes of %d data from stream\n"` print out ? e.g. If read() returns 0, it means the client has closed the connection

Comment: Reading 0 bytes of 4 data from stream

Comment: What value do you initialize `len` to?  It should be the maximum number of bytes `data` can contain.  If it's (implicitely?) initialized to 0, well...

Comment: @KarthikH read() returning 0 simply means the client has closed the connection.

Comment: Ok. If the client has closed the connection, then shouldnt it report an error?

Comment: @fvu, len is initialized to 4.

Comment: There should be no error if client closes connection in normal way. It is normal operation to just close connection. Maybe there is nothing wrong with the server but rather with the client? Is client also yours application? Maybe it is not sending what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your response everyone. Yes, it was the client that was causing the problem. I was closing the connection inadvertently